# Why does a "file exists" method in many languages return true for a directory?

Tags: file-io, methods, language-design

I know that it does in PHP, and I'm pretty sure it does in Java. I haven't used the latest versions of .NET, so I won't speak for them. It seems very awkward, but I was wondering if there was an underlying reason for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason is compatibility - anyone who has done 'check for existence' knows to exclude directories; changing that behaviour may confuse those who rely on that behaviour.

Secondly, the underlying code often does a check on the operating system for existence in a catlog of filesystem entries - to the OS, a directory is the same as a file. In other words, it's looking for an entry of 'xyz' in the catalog not a file with name 'xyz' in the catalog.

Backwards compatability is the main reason, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a formal reason why a directory is a file:

> Files (or links to files) can be
>   located in directories. However, more
>   generally, a directory can contain
>   either a list of files or a list of
>   links to files. Within this
>   definition, it is of paramount
>   importance that the term "file"
>   includes directories. This permits the
>   existence of directory hierarchies,
>   i.e., directories containing
>   subdirectories.

From Wikipedia, [‘Computer file’](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file#Identifying_and_organizing_files)

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use a “file exists” function to check a path before writing to it. In this use case the type of file is irrelevant, if there is a directory called “/home/foo” you won't be able to create a file called “/home/foo”

Also PHP, one of the languages you mentioned, provides several functions depending on what kind(s) of file you care about:

- [`file_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) will return TRUE for files, directories and symbolic links
- [`is_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) will return TRUE for files, but FALSE for directories and sym links
- [`is_dir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) will return TRUE for directories, but FALSE for files and sym links
- [`is_link()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php) will return TRUE for symbolic links, but FALSE for files and directories

Answer (score 0):

Part of the Unix philosophy is that "[everything is a file](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~arik/usail/concepts/filesystems/everything-is-a-file.html)".  This has influenced other environments as well to some degree.